# Caret Installation Error due to use of wrong library when proper one is installed locally

Tags: r, r-caret

I'm having difficulty installing caret (caret_6.0-77.tar.gz) due to it's insistence on using an older and incompatible library; "rlang" (0.1.1).  I have the proper version of rlang installed locally (0.1.2).  It will not use that version however.

**Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
      namespace ‘rlang’ 0.1.1 is already loaded, but >= 0.1.2 is required**

Is there a way to force the use of the local package rather than the package in the global library?

I'm using a corporate installation so I do not have write access to the global library.  That's why I'm using local library.

```
install.packages(file.choose(), repos = NULL, type = "source")
Installing package into ‘/xxxxx/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package ‘caret’ ...
** package ‘caret’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/tool/pandora64/.package/R-3.2.3/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -g -O2  -c caret.c -o caret.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -L/tool/pandora64/.package/R-3.2.3/lib64/R/lib -L/usr/local/lib64 -o caret.so caret.o -L/tool/pandora64/.package/R-3.2.3/lib64/R/lib -lR
installing to xxxxx/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/caret/libs
** R
** data
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Warning: replacing previous import by ‘plyr::ddply’ when loading ‘caret’
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace ‘rlang’ 0.1.1 is already loaded, but >= 0.1.2 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘caret’
* removing ‘xxxxx/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/caret’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘xxxx/R_Packages/R_Packages/Source/caret_6.0-77.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
>
```

Answer (score 0):

`caret` doesn't require `rlang`; one of its dependencies does.

I would suggest

1. starting with a clean R session
2. install the required version of `rlang` into your local library path
3. check `.libPaths()` to make sure that your local library path is before the canonical one (that you can't modify). [this could entirely be the issue]
4. load `caret`